# Migrating a C program from Linux to Windows

Tags: c, linux, windows

I want to open a file in C with the open() function,and this is the code I use:

```
int lire(){
    char buf[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    int fildes;
    char path[128];
    mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH;
    int flags = O_RDONLY;
    printf("\n%s-->Donner l'emplacement du fichier :%s ", CYAN_NORMAL, RESETCOLOR);
    scanf("%s", path);
    fildes = ouvrir(path, flags, mode);
    if(fildes == -1){
        return 0;
    }
    while ((bytesRead = read(fildes, buf, sizeof buf)) > 0)
    {
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, bytesRead);
    }
    close(fildes);
    return 1;
}

int ouvrir(char *path, int flags, mode_t mode)
{
        return open(path, flags, mode);
}
```

I've wrote this code for the first time in `Linux`, and It was working, but when I run it in `Windows` I got this error message:

```
error: 'S_IRUSR' undeclared (first use in this function)|
error: 'S_IWUSR' undeclared (first use in this function)|
error: 'S_IRGRP' undeclared (first use in this function)|
error: 'S_IROTH' undeclared (first use in this function)|
```

These are the headers I included:

```
#include <sys/types.h> //Specified in man 2 open
#include <sys/stat.h>    
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <fcntl.h> // open function
    #include <unistd.h> // close function
    #include "colors.h"
    #include "const.h"
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <string.h>
```

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: Which compiler on Windows ? Didn't you see any fatal error "unable to open include file .." ?

Comment: I use GNU GCC Compiler, And There is no a such fatal error

Comment: Isn't S_IRUSR, etc., in stat.h?

Comment: see my answer below and your headaches will go away :D

Answer (score 12):

With Windows you need to include `sys\stat.h`, and the mode flags available are `_S_IREAD` and `_S_IWRITE`, which can be combined if needed.  Documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0kc8e3z.aspx).

Note in particular this comment:

> If a value other than the above is specified for pmode (even if it would specify a valid pmode in another operating system) or any value other than the allowed oflag values is specified, the function generates an assertion in Debug mode and invokes the invalid parameter handler as described in Parameter Validation. If execution is allowed to continue, the function returns -1 and sets errno to EINVAL.